# Trigger formatting cells of DataGridView from the SelectedIndexChanged event of a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am implementing the following requests.

1. User select an item in a ComboBox.
2. The `SelectedIndexChanged` event handling code formats some of the cells according to the selected value of the ComboBox. However, it doesn't work.

.

```
void Combobox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        var c = GridView1.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            if (...some condition using selected value...) 
            {
                 row.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                 row.Cells[i].ToolTipText = "test";
            }
        }
    }
```

Question: Should it be added to event CellFormatting, .. events? However, the algorithm is depends on the event of combobox's `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: I have tested this code, and it works! May be problem in condition using selected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var c = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue==1){
                                row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                                row.Cells[0].ToolTipText = "test";
                        }

            else
            {
                        row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                        row.Cells[0].ToolTipText = "test";
                }
            }
    }

Thanks
```

Comment: would you please check if the particular cell is existing on the gridview which are you trying to format? or is there any problem on the selected value of the combobox? just for clarification. Because this code worked on my side. thanks.

Comment: I found out that the legacy program has events of `CellFormatting`, `PrePainting`, etc and it overwrote the style.

Comment: for test purpose drag a datagridview and combobox in the form. initialize datagridview with 2 cells. initialize combobox with test items. now on the selectedindexchanged event write the above code showing under the event braces. lets see what happens. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this in CellFormatting event..

Foreach loop

```
   DataGridViewTextBoxCell txt = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
   txt.Value = row.Cells[i].Value
   txt.ToolTipText = "test";
   txt.BackColor = Color.Green;
   row.Cells[i] = txt;
```